# Azure v2.0 in production prerequisite

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal, azure-hub

I am using Azure v2.0 for authenticating user and then call MS Graph API using access token provided by Azure v2.0. For using Azure v2.0 we need to register apoplication at [Microsoft App Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/). I am following the process mentione at [Register your app with the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_register_app_v2).

I am not able to understand if same procedure can be used to register app in production environment as well or not. If not then please guide on how to proceed for setting this up in production environment.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on `register app in production environment`? Do you intend to use the same application or want to create a new application?

Comment: @Gaurav - I have basically three environments as dev,test and production. I want to register three different application for this. So if I register application as mentioned at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_register_app_v2. Do I need to follow same procedure for generating appid that can be used in my production environment. I do believe that the api's which will be used will have different response rate for application registered for production use and test purpose

Comment: You're correct in your assumption. You will need to create separate applications for each of the environment. For separation of concerns, I would recommend creating separate Microsoft account for each environment so that you don't end up deleting production application by mistake.

Comment: So the process for setup is exactly same for appid in prod/test environment. Any restriction on type of microsoft account that I am using like it must be Azure AD account or Microsoft account (i.e. work vs account). As you are suggesting their is not difference in app for prodcution and test env ..

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  And one more question with this, can we revoke the permission granted by using Azurev2.0 endpoint. (Condition - User can  hold a personal account or belongs to different organization which is not same as the business acocunt domain used for application registration)

Comment: I have no idea about this. Sorry! But from what I understand, it is the user who will grant/revoke the permission to the application and not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for the response.